# Java android osm mapController set center

Tags: java, android, openstreetmap

I want to set a center in mapView by point and I want to see this point In the middle of the screen. But This point I see on the left top corner when I did this :

```
GeoPoint point= new GeoPoint(si.getListaVisible().get(x).lat, si.getListaVisible().get(x).lon);
      mapController.setCenter(point);
```

Comment: Can you tell us where/when you are calling `setCenter()`? Does the same thing happen when using `animateTo()`?

Comment: @scai I call this when I download a cordinates for this point,  I have lan and lon and when I calling setCenter() my point is on left top corner